# How to update pandas version in SageMaker notebook terminal?

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, anaconda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using SageMaker JupyterLab, but I found pandas is out of date, what's the process of updating it?

I tried this:
In terminal:

```
cd SageMaker
conda update pandas
```

The package has been updated to 1.0.5
but when I use this command in SageMaker instance:

```
import pandas
print(pandas,__version__)

return:
0.24.2
```

It didn't work at all, can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform any kind of upgrades or modification to the kernel of the notebook you can do this at launch by using [lifecycle configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html).

Comment: I had a look but not fully understand, should I run those codes in a terminal or something? Could you provide a step-by-step process? Many thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find where is 'in log stream [notebook-instance-name]/[LifecycleConfigHook].' and 'choose Create a new lifecycle configuration.' mentioned in this link.

Comment: This is a bash script that runs when you create a new notebook instance, the document I linked has the step by step under “To create a lifecycle configuration”. For examples of scripts you can use there are examples here: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples